# sql timesheet count by day for the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

my table looks like this:

```
select clocktime, for_UID, in1_out0 from timeclockentries

clocktime                   for_UID    in1_out0
2011-08-07 15:13:58.390 user193    1
2011-08-07 21:09:45.093 user193    0
2011-08-09 14:10:00.000 user193    1
2011-08-09 20:10:00.000 user193    0
```

I want the results to look like (assuming start of week is Saturday), separated by COLUMNS named 'day1', 'day2', etc.... (but for readability, i've typed them out with linefeeds) :

```
day1                       day2                       day3
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000    1900-01-01 05:55:46.700    1900-01-01 00:00:00.000   

day4                       day5                       day6
1900-01-01 06:00:00.000    1900-01-01 00:00:00.000    1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

day7
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

(i'm using sql2005)

below is what i'm using for a single day:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_gethoursbyday]
  @whichforUID varchar(20),
  @whichdate datetime
AS
BEGIN

;WITH CTE as(
SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() over (Partition by for_UID , in1_out0  Order by clocktime) id,
    clocktime,
    for_UID,
    in1_out0

FROM 
    kdhcastle.dbo.timeclockentries tc
WHERE 
         tc.for_UID = @whichforUID 
and month(tc.[clocktime]) = month(@whichdate)
and day(tc.[clocktime]) = day(@whichdate)
and year(tc.[clocktime]) = year(@whichdate)

    )
SELECT
     Cast(cast(sum(
        cast(outTime.clocktime as float) - cast(inTime.clocktime as float)
        )as datetime) as datetime) as 'hoursbydy'
FROM 
     CTE inTime
     INNER JOIN CTE outTime
     ON inTime.for_UID = outTime.for_UID
         AND inTime.id = outTime.id
        AND inTime.in1_out0 = 1
        and outTime.in1_out0 = 0

    END
```

Comment: Is there a guarantee that there will always be exactly 0 or 2 records for each day per user, and that the data will only ever cover a period of 7 days?  And would you like to add UID as a column to your new output?

Comment: no UID necessary for the output.  there could be an unlimited number of records per day per user. always 7 days.

Comment: And the other (more important) questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more verbose but my focus was (a) to avoid repeating expressions and (b) to simulate all of the input parameters intended to be fed to the stored procedure so that the results are filtered on the desired user / date. Note that the @whichdate parameter is reeled back to the preceding Saturday at midnight, regardless of which day of the week it is or what time is associated with it.

Input parameters:

```
DECLARE @whichdate DATETIME;
SET @whichdate = '2011-08-08T12:34:00';

DECLARE @whichforUID VARCHAR(32);
SET @whichforUID = 'user193';
```

Body (just comment out the DECLARE @t / INSERT @t lines, and change @t in the first CTE to the real table name:

```
SET @whichdate = DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @whichdate), @whichdate);
SET @whichdate = DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @whichdate));

DECLARE @t TABLE(clocktime DATETIME, for_UID VARCHAR(32), in1_out0 BIT);

INSERT @t SELECT '2011-08-07 15:13:58.390','user193',1
UNION ALL SELECT '2011-08-07 21:09:45.093','user193',0
UNION ALL SELECT '2011-08-09 14:10:00.000','user193',1
UNION ALL SELECT '2011-08-09 20:10:00.000','user193',0;

WITH s(dw, ct, in1_out0) AS
(
    SELECT 1 + (DATEDIFF(DAY, '2011-01-01', clocktime) % 7), 
        clocktime, in1_out0 FROM @t
        where for_UID = @whichforUID
        AND clocktime >= @whichdate
        AND clocktime < DATEADD(DAY, 7, @whichdate)
),
d(dw, min_ct, max_ct) AS 
(
    SELECT dw, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN in1_out0 = 1 THEN ct ELSE NULL END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN in1_out0 = 0 THEN ct ELSE NULL END)
    FROM s GROUP BY dw
),
x AS 
(
    SELECT d = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, min_ct, max_ct), 0), 
        dw FROM d
),
pvt AS (
    SELECT * FROM x PIVOT
    (MAX(d) FOR dw IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])) AS p
)
SELECT
    day1 = COALESCE([1], '19000101'),
    day2 = COALESCE([2], '19000101'),
    day3 = COALESCE([3], '19000101'),
    day4 = COALESCE([4], '19000101'),
    day5 = COALESCE([5], '19000101'),
    day6 = COALESCE([6], '19000101'),
    day7 = COALESCE([7], '19000101')
FROM pvt;
```

Comment: what is this line for: >>SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2010-12-31', clocktime) % 7,    and why have that date ?

Comment: It's just an arbitrary, known Sunday.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant Friday (added one instead of subtracted one). Anyway the reason this works is simply to avoid the +1 that would otherwise be required with Jan 1 as the base date (since Jan 1 is a Saturday). I'm only matching what the op requested - seems he wanted Sunday's data (2011-08-07) to fall under "day2" since the start of his week is Saturday.

Comment: The problem there is that `% 7` yield 0-6, not 1-7.  So, Saturday is then indeed 1, but Friday is then 0 and not 7.

Comment: Gotcha, corrected. I'm sure there are other edge cases not covered by the sample data (e.g. clock in with no clock out or vice versa).

Comment: the data is generated from within an outside program, and stored in the sql table - my goal with my original question is to achieve the desired results with a single exec call.

Comment: @kdhismgr don't place too much faith in an outside program producing perfect data.

Comment: so, if i change this line:  SELECT 1 + (DATEDIFF(DAY, '2011-01-01', clocktime) % 7),   to:  SELECT (DATEDIFF(DAY, '2011-01-01', clocktime) % 7),   then the output is correct.

Comment: If you change that line that way, the output doesn't seem to match your desired result as stated in the question.

Comment: i want saturday to be day 1, and friday to be day 7. if i don't change that line, it looks like friday is day1.

Comment: I just copied the code and ran it. The data from Sunday (aug 7) appeared in the day2 column, just like it is stated in your question. Could you try copying and pasting the code again please, and tell me what you changed to get that result?

Comment: ok, i opened a new query window and pasted the newest version above without changing anything. it works as expected. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 1 THEN Duration ELSE 0 END)    AS Day1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 2 THEN Duration ELSE 0 END)    AS Day2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 3 THEN Duration ELSE 0 END)    AS Day3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 4 THEN Duration ELSE 0 END)    AS Day4,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 5 THEN Duration ELSE 0 END)    AS Day5,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 6 THEN Duration ELSE 0 END)    AS Day6,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 7 THEN Duration ELSE 0 END)    AS Day7
FROM
(
  SELECT
    DATEDIFF(DAY, '2011 Jan 01', clocktime) % 7 + 1  AS DayOfWeek,
    CAST(MAX(clocktime) - MIN(clocktime) AS FLOAT)   AS Duration
  FROM
    yourTable
  GROUP BY
    for_UID,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, '2011 Jan 01', clocktime)
)
  AS [data]
```

Comment: Changed to base the `DATEDIFF` on a known Saturday.  The `% 7` then yields 0-6 for Sat-Fri, so +1 to give 1-7.  Values for different weeks are aggregated together into a single record.

Comment: I would suggest using a safe date format. '2011 Jan 01' will fail in many cultures other than US/UK English, whereas '20110101' will never fail.

Comment: I missed the comments to the question, sorry. +1 for the solution.